# How to define a Reinforcement Learning episode when dealing with dataset of customer's features?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

so one of friends sent me some problem he was working on lately and I couldn't help but to wonder how could it be solved using Q-learning. The statement is as follows :

Given the following datasets, the objective is to find a suitable strategy per customer contract to maximize Gain and minimize Cost according to the characteristics of the customer.

train.csv: 5 000 independent rows, 33 columns.

Columns description:

• Day (1, 2 or 3): on which day the strategy was applied.

• 28 variables (A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, BB): characteristics of the individual;

• Gain: the gain for this individual for the corresponding strategy;

• Cost: the cost for this individual for the corresponding strategy;

• Strategy (0, 1 or 2): the strategy applied on this individual;

• Success: 1 if the strategy succeeded, 0 otherwise.

If Success is 1, then the net Gain is Gain - Cost, and if Success is 0, consider a standardized cost of 5.

2. test.csv: 2 000 independent rows, 31 columns.

Columns description:

• Index: 0 to 1999, unique for each row.

• Day (4): on which day the strategy will be applied.

• 28 variables (A, B, C, ..., Z, AA, BB): characteristics of the client;

• Gain: the gain for this individual for the corresponding strategy;

• Cost: the cost for this individual for the corresponding strategy;

So from what I understood the train.csv file is used to build a Q-Learning model and the test one for generating a strategy and predicting a Success.

My main question is :

How to formulate this problem as RL ? How to define an episode ? Since the training data is labeled, this could be clearly a classification problem ( predicting the strategy ), but I have no idea how to solve it using RL ( Q-learning ideally ). Any idea will be helpful. Thank you.